# Is there an idiom or expression saying or implying that gambling is a good thing?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom or expression saying or implying that gambling is a good thing? I am pretty sure there are idioms about gambling, but I am not sure if any of them are "positive".

Comment: I am not going to answer because I do not know a saying that specifically advocates gambling, but there are certainly sayings that advocate enjoying life while it lasts, e,g. *you can't take it with you* and *enjoy it while you can.* The wonderful thing about folk sayings is that they almost always come in contrary pairs so you can find an adage to support any position. I suspect that with reference to gambling there is something similar to *It's better to have loved and lost than never loved at all.*

Comment: I think some context about what you're trying to say would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The following idiom has a positive connotation about taking risks:

> ***[Nothing ventured, nothing gained:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nothing-ventured--nothing-gained)***
>
> - If you don't risk anything, you won't gain anything.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is

> you've gotta be in it, to win it

[idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you%27ve+got+to+be+in+it+to+win+it)

The implication is that you should gamble as that's the only way to win! Lotteries and the like often use this.